# Values for Array Terms in z3 Models

Tags: z3

I am using z3 for my research and I have the following problem. I am analyzing the model of a satisfiable formula that contains arrays and uninterpreted functions. I would like to inspect inspect particular array entries.

In the examples of the z3 guide, one can access such values.
E.g., for questions like

```
(get-value ((select my_array 0)))
```

one gets answers like

```
(((select my_array 0) 1))
```

indicating that the value of `my_array` at position `0` is `1`.

However, the answer I get looks like

```
(((select my_array 0) (select Array!val!0 0)))
```

which is not very helpful at all.

Also, at the beginning of the model I get a block that looks like this:

```
  ;; universe for (Array Int Int):
  ;;   Array!val!10 Array!val!6 Array!val!0 Array!val!5 Array!val!9 Array!val!1 Array!val!11 Array!val!4 Array!val!2 Array!val!7 Array!val!3 Array!val!8 
  ;; -----------
  ;; definitions for universe elements:
  (declare-fun Array!val!10 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!6 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!0 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!5 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!9 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!1 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!11 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!4 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!2 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!7 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!3 () (Array Int Int))
  (declare-fun Array!val!8 () (Array Int Int))
  ;; cardinality constraint:
  (forall ((x (Array Int Int)))
          (and (= x Array!val!10)
               (= x Array!val!6)
               (= x Array!val!0)
               (= x Array!val!5)
               (= x Array!val!9)
               (= x Array!val!1)
               (= x Array!val!11)
               (= x Array!val!4)
               (= x Array!val!2)
               (= x Array!val!7)
               (= x Array!val!3)
               (= x Array!val!8)))
  ;; -----------
```

I don't really understand the meaning of this, but somehow this seems to be related to my problem, as a similar block does *not* turn up for the simple examples in the guide. Does anyone know what triggers this behaviour of z3 or how it can be avoided?

After some experimentation, I found a "minimal" example that exhibits the undesired behavior. It seems to have something to do with using uninterpreted functions in index expressions.

```
(declare-fun my_function ((Int)(Int)) Int)
(declare-fun my_array () (Array Int Int))

(assert
  (=
    (select my_array (my_function 0 1))
    (select my_array (my_function 1 0))
  )
)

(check-sat)  
(get-model)
(get-value ((select my_array (my_function 0 1))))
(get-value ((my_function 0 1)))
```

z3's response to this is:

```
sat 
(model
 ;; universe for (Array Int Int):
 ;; Array!val!0
 ;; -----------
 ;; definitions for universe elements:
 (declare-fun Array!val!0 () (Array Int Int))
 ;; cardinality constraint:
 (forall ((x (Array Int Int))) (= x Array!val!0))
 ;; -----------
 (define-fun my_array () (Array Int Int)
 Array!val!0)
 (define-fun my_function ((x!1 Int) (x!2 Int)) Int
 (ite (and (= x!1 0) (= x!2 1)) 2
 (ite (and (= x!1 1) (= x!2 0)) 3
 2)))
 )
 (((select my_array (my_function 0 1)) (select Array!val!0 2)))
 (((my_function 0 1) 2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SMT, a "logic" specifies which theories are available for constructing formulas. For example, if the command `(set-logic QF_UFLIA)` is used, uninterpreted functions and linear integer arithmetic is available. When a logic is not specified using the command `set-logic`. Z3 tries to guess the logic automatically for the user, and only "installs" the necessary theories. In your example, Z3 is incorrectly guessing that your example does not need the array theory. Thus, `(Array Int Int)` is treated as a uninterpreted sort. 
That is why Z3 is assuming (Array Int Int) is an uninterpreted sort, and providing an interpretation for it in the generated model. This is a bug, I will fix it for the next release. 
In the meantime, you can use one of the following approaches to avoid this bug:

- Specify a logic that contains the array theory. Example: add `(set-logic QF_AUFLIA)` in the beginning of your example.
- Disable automatic configuration (Z3 will install all available theories). Add command `(set-option :auto-config false)`.